# Prevent aria2c from uploading torrent files?

Tags: command-line, downloads, bittorrent

How do I prevent aria2c from uploading torrent files at download time?
And aria2c is safe for that ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This very subject was addressed to one of the aria2c developers earlier this year:

- [Is it possible to turn off BitTorrent upload completely?](https://github.com/aria2/aria2/issues/854)

And unfortunately the answer was pretty clear in the negative:

> There is no way to completely turn off BitTorrent uploading at the
>   moment.

Your only real option is to experiment with the following two options which will go close to what you are after:

#### --seed-ratio=Ratio

Specify share ratio. Seed completed torrents until share ratio reaches RATIO.
You are strongly encouraged to specify equals or more than 1.0 here. Specify
0.0 if you intend to do seeding regardless of share ratio. If --seed-time
option is specified along with this option, seeding ends when at least one
of the conditions is satisfied. Default: 1.0

An example for your purposes could be:

```
aria2c --seed-ratio=0.1 file.torrent
```

#### –max-upload-limit=Speed

Specifies the max of upload rate. An example for your purposes would be:

```
aria2c --max-upload-limit=5K file.torrent
```

Answer (score 6):

There is now a way to disable it

https://aria2.github.io/manual/en/html/aria2c.html#cmdoption-seed-time

> Specifying --seed-time=0 disables seeding after download completed.

Comment: This option disables seeding **after** download completed. But the question was about **at download time**.